# How to call a function when the text box received a value in jsp page?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a jsp page with some bar graphs.
I'm using an onClick function (and some JavaScript) to copy the name to a text box. The problem I'm running into is I'm not able to use the value of this text box anywhere else. I need to set that variable in a session, and so it needs to be sent to a database.

Here is some of my code:

```
popfunction(a)
{
     var  x ;
     var r=confirm("Press OK to add stage !!!");
     if (r==true)
     {
          document.getElementById("res").value = a; //coming into a test box 
     }
     else
     {
          return ;
     }
}
```

(Note that the code only proceeds when the user clicks "OK".)

How can a set a session variable of the selected bar graph?

Comment: Do you have form for this jsp?

Comment: Can you read a cookie on the JSP page?

Comment: @Prasad No i dont have a form and i cannot use a form for this page.....

Comment: @Volter9 no i dont know how to use cookie in jsp or any other lang

Comment: @Kunal0615 Do you know how to use sessions in JSP?

Comment: @Volter9 i know how to use them.. but as i mentioned in the problem,iam extracting the var. using javaScript,and i cannot use a Javascript var to set session.. if that is possible my problem will solved..

Comment: You can use AJAX to send data to you JSP page.

Comment: @Volter9 i dont know how to use AJAX  :/ sry for that but i found another sol for this.. can i also ask u to vote up this question as my account has been blocked.. and i cannot ask any more question ..plz if u can